# AVAudioPlayer plays in iOS Simulator but not on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I'm building an app which has to play a mp3 file. For that issue, I'm using AVAudioPlayer following the indications I have been reading from others post. 
But my problem is, the code (I have attached bellow) works on the iOS Simulator, but when I try to use it in my iPhone, it doesn't work...
I hope any of you could help me with this issue.

**File .h:**

```
#import "UIKit/UIKit.h"
#import "AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *player;

@end
```

**File .m:**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize player;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"beep_7" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSLog(@"Audio path: %@", soundFilePath);

    NSError *error;
    self.player =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath] error:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else {
        [self.player setDelegate:self];
        [self.player setNumberOfLoops:3]; //just to make sure it is playing my file several times
        self.player.volume = 1.0f;

        if([self.player prepareToPlay]) //It is always ready to play
            NSLog(@"It is ready to play");
        else
            NSLog(@"It is NOT ready to play ");

        if([self.player play]) //It is always playing
            NSLog(@"It should be playing");
        else
            NSLog(@"An error happened");
    }
}

-(void)audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur: (AVAudioPlayer *)player error:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur -> Error in audioPlayer: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
-(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying: (AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag{
    NSLog(@"audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying");
}
-(void)audioPlayerBeginInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)player{
    NSLog(@"audioPlayerBeginInterruption");
}
-(void)audioPlayerEndInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)player{
    NSLog(@"audioPlayerEndInterruption");
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to check when the audio (or image) is working (shown) in the simulator and not on the device is the spelling of the audio - file you are trying to access.

Since Mac OSX is NOT case sensitive but iOS is this means that an image spelled `iMage.png` and accessed as `image.png` in your code will show in the simulator but NOT on your iPhone.

The other thing to check could be that you have accidentally hit the physical mute button on your iPhone. (Happened to me last week)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, I hit the physical mute botton and I didnt realize about that! thanks